# What is the use of @jsControl helper in dust.js?

Tags: dust.js

I see that dust.js has @jsControl helper. Reference http://www.slideshare.net/veenabs/curious-case-of-dust Slide #29. I would like to know what it is and when and where to use. And I dont find the implementation of it in https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers/blob/master/lib/dust-helpers.js

Comment: Looks like a custom helper; it's not in the dust source. If you want to know I'm sure the author of the slides will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, its a helper used internally at linkedin, which is used to attach javascript to given element. https://github.com/smfoote/Swiffer.js/issues/12